# How to use ByteBuffer for short to byte[] conversion?

Tags: java

I have a class, `Packet`, which I wrote to populate a `byte[]` array of 516 bytes. 2 for `packetNum` (`short`), 2 for `authKey` (`short`), and 512 for `audio` (`byte[]`). Inside my `Packet` class is a method which combines these attributes together to create a `byte[]` array of size 516, to send to a recipient:

```
public byte[] toByteArray() {
    byte[] fullArray = new byte[516];

    ByteBuffer packetNumBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
    packetNumBuffer.putShort(this.packetNum);
    byte[] packetNumArray = packetNumBuffer.array();

    ByteBuffer authKeyBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
    authKeyBuffer.putShort(this.authKey);
    byte[] authKeyArray = authKeyBuffer.array();

    System.arraycopy(packetNumArray, 0, fullArray, 0, packetNumArray.length);
    System.arraycopy(authKeyArray, 0, fullArray, packetNumArray.length, authKeyArray.length);
    System.arraycopy(this.audio, 0, fullArray, authKeyArray.length, this.audio.length);
    return fullArray;
}
```

Now, when testing the received packet, my `packetNum` (which increments before creating next `Packet`) is transmitted successfully - however, the `authKey` and `audio` are completely wrong. Here's the output of my code, which creates a new `Packet` with `short authKey = 10` and `short packetNum = 0`:

```
Packet number: 0
Auth key = -7936
Packet number: 1
Auth key = 19201
Packet number: 2
Auth key = 31490
Packet number: 3
Auth key = -1
Packet number: 4
Auth key = -2
Packet number: 5
Auth key = -3
Packet number: 6
Auth key = -4
Packet number: 7
Auth key = -3
Packet number: 8
Auth key = -2
Packet number: 9
Auth key = -1
Packet number: 10
Auth key = 8192
```

The auth key spits random numbers for each packet, when it should be `10` for all of them. This leads me to believe my method isn't populating my `fullArray` as expected. Can anyone spot something I've done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error lies here

```
System.arraycopy(this.audio, 0, fullArray, authKeyArray.length, this.audio.length);
```

The starting position is `authKeyArray.length`
But it should be `authKeyArray.length + packetNumArray.length`

---

Anyway, `System.arraycopy` is one of those methods to absolutely avoid.
My suggestion is, use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(516);
outputStream.write(packetNumArray);
outputStream.write(authKeyArray);
outputStream.write(audio);
final byte[] fullArray = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Isn't it **a lot** more elegant?

Comment: Fantastic. Thankyou.

Comment: @eddiewastaken it's nothing. I like elegant code so I'd pick the ByteArrayOutputStream :)